# Simple graphQL query gives error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, graphql

I am trying to use [graphql](/questions/tagged/graphql) for one of the `GET` request based on an id. Here's the code:

```
const { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

EmployeeService.prototype.getEmployee = function() {
  // Construct a schema
  const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
      employee(id="12345") {
        id
        items {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  // The root provides a resolver function
  let root = {
    employee: () => id
  };

  // Run the GraphQL query
  graphql(schema, '{ employee }', root).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

Trying to follow the documentation on http://graphql.org/graphql-js/.
I get a GraphQL error: `"Syntax Error GraphQL request (3:19) Expected :, found =↵↵2:     type Query {↵3:       employee (id="12345") {↵                     ^↵4:       id↵"`
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maybe mixing things a little bit up. The schema and resolvers are part of your API and are not needed to make a query on a client. Just for demonstration purposes here a valid schema definition (that would normally run on a API server):

```
let schema = buildSchema(`
  type Item {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
  }

  type Employee {
    id: Int!
    items: [Item]
  }

  type Query {
    employee(id: Int!): Employee
  }
`);
```

You then define your types and resolvers (simplified examples):

```
class Employee {
    constructor(id, items) {
        this.id = id;
        this.items = items;
    }
}

let root = {
    employee: ({id}) => {
        return new Employee(id, [{id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Item2'}]);
    }
};
```

You can then run a query:

```
const query = `
  {
    employee(id: 1) {
      id,
      items {
        id,
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

graphql(schema, query, root).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

To run actual queries against a remote API have a look at [GraphQL clients](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql-clients/) like [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/) or [lokka](https://github.com/kadirahq/lokka)